# Accessing Collections

Tags: collections, laravel-5.4, relationships

Can i ask for help??

so i have this relationship with bank accounts + the user who can access it

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\BankAccount', 'permissions', 'user_id', 
'account_id');
```

and then ill pass it to my view

```
$view->with('access', User::where('id', $user->id)->with('bankAccounts')->get());
```

this is how i access it

```
@foreach($access as $account)
     <li>{{ $account->bankAccounts }}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

it gives me this output

```
[{"id":1,"account_name":"MBTC Mambaling","type":"1","branch":"Mambaling","account_number":"331-7-331504366","contact_person":"Armand Dela Cruz","contact_number":null,"created_at":"2017-06-26 03:16:13","updated_at":"2017-06-26 03:16:13","pivot":{"user_id":2,"account_id":1,"created_at":"2017-06-26 03:16:39","updated_at":"2017-06-26 03:16:39"}}]
```

how can i access each of the data present in the collection??
thanks for answering in advance guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a collection of users with the following query

`User::where('id', $user->id)->with('bankAccounts')->get()`

I would suggest altering this to something like the following:

`User::find($user->id)->bankAccounts()`

This will return the users attached `bankAccounts` as a collection. You can then access the properties like so:

```
@foreach($access as $account)
    <li>{{ $account->account_name}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: for example the bankAccounts ive attached has to tables...the bank_accounts table and the bank_account_types table..and the are in the permissions table where i had merge them..so my question is how can i access the bank_account_types table because i can only access the bank_accounts table this code of yours

Comment: You would need a relation on your bankAccount model which you can then access when you loop through the array of accounts. I would suggest reading the following documentation page in the Laravel documentation which should explain everything perfectly: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships